# Постановка запятой

Tags: пунктуация

"Для тех(,) для кого это важно" - нужна тут запятая или нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно нужна!
Тут же очевидное придаточное предложение.
А почему сомнения?

Answer (score 0):

Дважды повторять "для" - ошибка. Предложение построено неправильно. Лучше написать "Для тех, кому это важно"

Comment: Ошибки нет.  
Лучше - может быть.